# ember acceptance test error 'assertion failed' because of rootElement

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing, ember-qunit

does anyone have experience with acceptance test errors?  i am getting the error "Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to add 'ember-application' class to rootElement. Make sure you set rootElement to the body or an element in the body."  can't find any answers to this anywhere.  please help.  i am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a `rootElement` other than body set in your `config/environment.js` file (specifically dev environment). Make sure that element (e.g., `#someDivName`) is in your index.html file in the `tests` folder. You'll need to restart your ember server after adding this.